# Space/ no space between css selectors and classes of elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

What's the difference between the selection of a css selector (for example: p) and a class of an element (.cat)?

```
 p.cat{
}
```

vs

```
p .cat{
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `p.cat` selects paragraph elements with the `cat` class.
2. `p .cat` selects all elements with the `cat` class that are descendants of paragraph elements.